# unspecified error while selecting childitem from a webtable

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am getting an unspecified error while click on a link from a webtable. I know this error pop ups when index value, row, column values are inccorect. In this case, I am sure all of the mandate fields are correct.I've no clue why the error happens. I can only click the 2nd row,1 column, index "0" link & not any further. Any help would be appreciated.

`Set MyBrw=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*")`

`If browser("creationtime:=1").Exist Then`

`set ProdtTBL=browser("creationtime:=1").page("name:=.*").webtable("column names:=;Product Name;Part Number;Unit Price;Action","cols:=5")`

`ProdtTBL.ChildItem(2,2,"link",0).click`

`MyBrw.webedit("name:=qty1","html tag:=input").Set "1"`

`MyBrw.webbutton("name:=Add Product","html tag:=input").Click`

`MyBrw.image("html tag:=IMG","title:=Products","index:=1").click`
`browser("creationtime:=1").Sync`
 `ProdtTBL.ChildItem(6,2,"link",5).highlight`
`MyBrw.webedit("name:=qty2","html tag:=input").Set "10"`

`End If`

Comment: Try the function from this link http://www.aneejian.com/qtp-function-to-click-link-in-web-table/

Comment: This is not some general error, this error depends upon your application. If you are able to access link from one row you should be able to access same type of link from other rows as well. Also you need to write the childitem 6,2 line on new line and not on the same line which has sync statement.